# Are standardized tail volumes used for swept wing GA aircraft like in straight wing designs? If so, what are they?

Tags: aerodynamics

Are standardized tail volumes used for swept wing GA aircraft like in straight wing designs?

If so, what are they?

I understand that after roughly 100 years of aircraft design, there are rules of thumb/guiding principles to use regarding tail volume sizing.

As per the MIT open course notes for GA straight winged aircraft:

Horizontal Tail Volume: .3 -.6

Vertical Tail Volume: .02-.05

If applicable, what are the above tail volume values for GA aircraft with swept wings of roughly 20 deg?

Assumptions on stability/geometry of swept wing vs straight wing ( I stand to be corrected):

1. Pitch stability: the horizontal tail volume would be smaller as the swept wings provide added pitch stability.
2. Roll Stability: I'm told dihedral is a lot less then on straight wings, so better roll stability.
3. Yaw Stability: no idea

Comment: the ranges of those "MIT notes" should be setting off alarm bells, you need to figure **distance from** CG as well, yielding a $torque$ value.  Also, do you have 1 reason to sweep the wings of a GA plane back 20 degrees?

Comment: @Robert DiGiovanni: re sweep back - because it looks cool on an ultralight

Comment: Can't argue with that!  Maybe go with 5-7 degrees for starters.  It will help yaw stability.  But more sweep can create a dangerous pitch up on stall, as the wing tips stall first.  Washout will solve this, or slats, but separation of wing (lift) and tail (control), as in a Piper Cub is square 1.  Boring, but **safe**.

Comment: @ Robert DiGiovanni: Do you mean 5-7 deg sweep is better in yaw stability than 20 deg? Why is that?

Comment: no, adequate yaw stability is easily produced with flat sides and a vertical stabilizer, too many negatives in a 20 degree swept wing.  Just compare efficiency of straight wing to anything else.  In terms of safety, a highly swept wing would be 3rd, behind delta.